# What is the accepted ADS-B quality indicator value from EASA/FAA?

Tags: faa-regulations, easa-regulations, ads-b

I'm doing research that has to do with the ADS-B quality indicators. With the ADS-B quality indicators I've received, I want to compare them with EASA's or FAA's requirements for each ADS-B Version (260, 260A, 260B) and see if they have been met.

I am having trouble finding the right document that tells me the minimum requirement. The quality indicators I've received are NIC, NACp, NACv, SIL, GVA, and SDA. At the end, I want to show the statistics of how many *actually* complies with the minimum requirements declared by EASA/FAA *per* ADS-B version.